# Keep Navigational Bar from Overlapping Other Elements in CSS

Tags: css, html

I am able to get my dropdown navigation to stay at the top using absolute positioning, but it squishes the left side and everything at the top goes behind the navigation.

[image: Screenshot of my Issue]

How can I get my navigation to stop overlapping everything else with the `position:absolute` property? My nav elements are in my CSS, so an invisible `<div>` won't work.

The following is the HTML in my header.php document:

```
<center><nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/arcade">Arcade</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/arcade/action">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/arcade">Arcade</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/puzzle">Puzzle</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/vehicle">Vehicle</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/violence">Violence</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/defense">Defense</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/rpg">RPG</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Watch</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/watch/tv">TV Shows</a></li>
            <li><a href="/watch/movies">Movies</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Extras</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/reviews">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news">Updates</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/support">Support</a></li>
</ul>
</nav></center>
```

The following is the CSS I am using for the background color and positioning before the position is added:

```
nav{
    background-color:#989898;
    margin: 0px -12.5%;
}
```

Now the CSS after I add positioning:

```
nav{
    background-color:#989898;
    margin: 0px -12.5%;
            position:absolute;
            z-index:1000;
}
```

My website is [www.gameshank.com/](http://www.gameshank.com/)!

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I do not see any squishing to the left or content being lost behind the nav in Chrome, FF or IE. Post a snapshot of the problem.

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

When using `position:absolute` it removes the element from the document flow. The best way to prevent `position:absolute` elements from overlapping other elements is to use the margin properties to your advantage.

Try adding this to your CSS (differences noted with asterisks so don't add that to the code):

```
nav {
    background-color: #989898;
    margin-left: -10%; /****  Remove other margin: 0 -12.5%; */
    margin-top: -100px; /*****/
    width: 100%; /****/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}

#logo {  /**** This is all new. You can change to a different name if you need to.*/
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

Add this to your HTML `<center>` tag which immediately follows the `<center>` tag holding the `<nav>`.

```
<center id="logo"> ... </center>
```

---

On a different note, you should consider doing a significant rewrite of all that code. That site is using depreciated tags such as `<center>` and `<font>` for styles that CSS can handle better along side HTML5 elements such as `<nav>`.

Comment: It took off the navigation completely. Any ideas?

Comment: @AustinBunker I don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish. I also don't understand what you mean by "it took off the navigation completely."

Comment: @fredsbend Go to the website again, and the dropdown navigation is missing from the site. And I want it to stick to the top of the page even when you scroll.

Comment: @AustinBunker You question needs a rewrite then. Completely different thing than what it currently implies that you want.

Comment: @fredsbend I'll change it to what I had for the question then, and go from there with more research. Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: @AustinBunker See `position:fixed`. That will keep the element in the same spot on the window (scrolling will not move it).

Comment: @fredsbend It worked, but formed a new problem. Now it goes to the right of the page. Taking out the <center> tag moves it to the left again.

Comment: @Austin Remove the center tag then try `top:0` and `width:100%` on the nav tag.